# Django CBV - get url variable for use in class, error self s not defined

Tags: python, django

I am passing and trying to use site_id in my add form. I want to pre fill and hide the site_data field with the site ID in the url. and then use that variable to pass some more information to the context too.

my CBV is as such:

```
class AddSubnet(CreateView):
    model = SiteSubnets
    template_name = "sites/edit_subnet.html"
    fields = ['device_data', 'site_data', 'subnet', 'subnet_type', 'circuit', 'vlan_id', 'peer_desc']
    site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
    site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=site_id) 

    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('config.add_subnet')))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AddSubnet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
            return reverse_lazy("sites:site_detail_subnets", args = (site_id,))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['SiteID']=site_id
        context['SiteName']=site.location
        context['active_subnets']='class="active"'
        #
        return context
```

this currently yields with:

```
  File "/itapp/itapp/sites/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/itapp/itapp/sites/views.py", line 984, in <module>
    class AddSubnet(CreateView):
  File "/itapp/itapp/sites/views.py", line 988, in AddSubnet
    site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

EDIT:

url is as such

```
url(r'^site/add_subnet/(?P<site_id>[0-9]+)$', views.AddSubnet.as_view(), name='add_subnet'),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class AddSubnet(CreateView):
    site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
    site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=site_id)
```

You can't access `self` like this in the class definition. This code runs when the module is loaded. There isn't a request yet, so `self.kwargs` does not exist.

You could move the code into the dispatch method instead:

```
@method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('config.add_subnet')))
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
    self.site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=self.site_id) 
    return super(AddSubnet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then use `self.site_id` and `self.site` in other methods.

Comment: im getting an error "context['SiteID']=self.site_id" - 'AddSubnet' object has no attribute 'site_id'

Comment: If you set `self.site_id` in `dispatch` before calling `super()`, then you shouldn't get that error.

Comment: Actually it doesn't look like the SiteID is not being passed as im getting reverse url issues against SiteID

Comment: @Alisdair is the url correct to enable referencing site_id?

Comment: I always said to set `self.site_id` in the dispatch method, that didn't change in the edit.

Comment: Your URL has `(?P<site_id>[0-9]+)`, so `self.kwargs['site_id']` should work fine *inside* methods.

Comment: thank you, do I need to use self.kwargs['site_id'] in each method separately or can I reference it in dispatch for use in all other methods within the same class?

Comment: We're going round in circles here. If you set `self.site_id` in `dispatch` before calling `super()`, then you should be able to use `self.site_id` inside other methods. You can use `self.kwargs['site_id']` inside other methods if you prefer, but then there's not much point setting `self.site_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You have written invalid syntax. remove below two lines from the code

```
site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=site_id)
```

write it in method`get_context_data`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AddSubnet, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
    site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=site_id)
    context['SiteID']=site_id
    context['SiteName']=site.location
    context['active_subnets']='class="active"'
    return context
```